# Reordering factor by another column

Tags: r

I am trying to reorder the levels of a factor by sorting, while maintaining the factor groupings. However it's not as simple as merely sorting the levels or labels. Here is an example data frame:

```r
dat <- data.frame(trt = c('0_m', '0.2_m', '0.4_m', '0.6_m'), letter = factor(c("b", "c", "a", "b")), value = c(2, 3, 1, 2.1))

dat
#    trt letter value
# 1   0_m      b   2.0
# 2 0.2_m      c   3.0
# 3 0.4_m      a   1.0
# 4 0.6_m      b   2.1
```

The levels of the letter column are already sorted alphabetically, but you'll notice that they are assigned in the order of the numeric `value` column.

```r
levels(dat$letter)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

The dataframe here is sorted by the `trt` column. The ultimate objective is to sort the `letter` column alphabetically as you go down the rows, while preserving any levels that have the same label. For example, what I would like to achieve is the following output:

```r
dat
#    trt letter value
# 1   0_m      a   2.0
# 2 0.2_m      b   3.0
# 3 0.4_m      c   1.0
# 4 0.6_m      a   2.1
```

The complication is that this is within a function that will be presented with an arbitrary set of letters/factor labels to be sorted alphabetically, so I can't just manually order them.
I feel like this should be relatively straight-forward with some combination of `factor()`, and the `levels` and `labels` arguments, but I just can't quite see it. Also, I would prefer a base R solution if possible, to avoid adding an extra dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should accomplish what you're looking for. You should be able to specify a column number with square bracket notation (e.g. `[,2]`) or something else robust in case you don't want to specify `letter`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  trt = c('0_m', '0.2_m', '0.4_m', '0.6_m'),
  letter = factor(c("b", "c", "a", "b")),
  value = c(2, 3, 1, 2.1))

dat
#    trt letter value
# 1   0_m      b   2.0
# 2 0.2_m      c   3.0
# 3 0.4_m      a   1.0
# 4 0.6_m      b   2.1

levels(dat$letter) <- sort(unique(dat$letter))[order(unique(dat$letter))]
dat
     trt letter value
# 1   0_m      a   2.0
# 2 0.2_m      b   3.0
# 3 0.4_m      c   1.0
# 4 0.6_m      a   2.1
```

Additionally, it may be useful to cache the unique values of the `letter` column before resetting the levels, instead of computing the unique values twice.